# iOS UITableView - once sorted, a cell is scrolled on top of a Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use the next code to change position of a cell:

```
self.tableView.moveRow(at: moveFromIndex, to: moveToIndex)
```

Once the cell is moved, it starts scrolling on top of a header

What could the reason?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and add all the appropriate code to the question to help us to help you:)

Comment: I guess the problem is not `moveRow` since this is used millions of time. Must be somewhere else in your code - please povide a minimal reproducible example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to switch to the default headers instead of custom. It didn't help. As a next step, I'll try to compile the project from scratch. Maybe it could help me to find an answer.